# If I use SELECT WHERE to find data, how do I return the column's name that data was under?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm not even sure where to start with the SELECT query itself but imagine I have a table below:

```
ID   Environment  Position1  Position2   Position3
1    Operations   Tech       Survey      Phone
2    Warehouse    Stocker    Maintenance Trucker
3    Office       Logger     Janitor
```

How would I do a SELECT query to give me the column name when I search for particular position name but I need to know which column its under?

Example:

```
SELECT columnname 
FROM table 
WHERE Position1 = 'Janitor' OR Position2 = 'Janitor' OR Position3 = 'Janitor'
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do this but the idea is each user is assigned Position1-3 and an Environment. If they are moved to another environment, they keep Position# but the label for it changes.

This data is bogus and honestly more confusing as I don't want to give away the real data. It's possible I have my tables set up bad.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't have 3 columns in the first place. Use another table that has a separate row for each position number, and a foreign key to this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT CASE 'Janitor'
        WHEN Position1 THEN 'Position1'
        WHEN Position2 THEN 'Position2'
        ELSE 'Position3'
    END AS columnname
FROM table
WHERE 'Janitor' IN (Position1, Position2, Position3)
```

But it would be better to normalize your data, with a table like this. `table1_id` is a foreign key to your original table.

```
table1_id   PositionNum Position
1           1           Tech
1           2           Survey
1           3           Phone
2           1           Stocker
2           2           Maintenance
2           3           Trucker
3           1           Logger
3           2           Janitor

SELECT PositionNum
FROM thisTable
WHERE Position = 'Janitor'
```

Comment: You are right, I went ahead made a positions table as described and its much easier to work. I was way over complicating it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select
   ID,
   Environment,
   (
        Case
            When Position1 = N'Janitor' Then N'Position1'
            When Position2 = N'Janitor' Then N'Position2'
            When Position3 = N'Janitor' Then N'Position3'
            When Position4 = N'Janitor' Then N'Position4'
            Else N'none'
        End
    ) As ColumnName
From Table
WHERE Position1 = N'Janitor' Or Position2 = N'Janitor' Or Position3 = N'Janitor' Or Position4 = N'Janitor'
```